# React onClick event for multiple divs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an onClick event that adds a classname for each of these elements without writing out three different functions. The event is fired on all three when one is clicked, however. How can I modify this so that the onClick only works for the one that is clicked?

```
const userVote = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          condition: false
        }
      },
      handleClick: function() {
        this.setState({
          condition: !this.state.condition
        });
      },


    render() {
        return(

                <div onClick={this.handleClick} className= { this.state.condition ? "positive active" : "positive"}></div>

                <div onClick={this.handleClick} className= { this.state.condition ? "neutral active" : "neutral"}>Not Sure</div>

                <div onClick={this.handleClick} className= { this.state.condition ? "negative active" : "negative"}></div>

        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Can multiple div remain active at the same time? or If I click on another div then previously clicked div becomes inactive?

Comment: Only one at a time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, you want only one div active at a time. You can maintain a single state variable which will keep track of an active div.

```
handleClick: function(divName) {
    this.setState({
        activeDiv: divName
    });
}

<div>
   <div onClick={() => this.handleClick('div1')} className= { this.state.activeDiv === 'div1' ? "positive active" : "positive"}>Div1</div>

   <div onClick={() => this.handleClick('div2')} className= { this.state.activeDiv === 'div2' ? "neutral active" : "neutral"}>Div2</div>

   <div onClick={() => this.handleClick('div3')} className= { this.state.activeDiv === 'div3' ? "negative active" : "negative"}>Div3</div>
</div>
```

I've created a state variable named `activeDiv` which will keep track of an active div, and when applying `className` you can check whether the current `div` is active or not.

Here, is the working Plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YMnGh0AX9kZXHdtvHUfE?p=preview) (ES6 Syntax)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7s40jqt/) (ES5 Syntax)

PS: You'll need to open browser console to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

- First of all, you need to return just one div on render's return, so. encapsulate it
- Modify a little bit your `condition` on this.state
- Add another parameter on onClick function

Something like that:

```
const userVote = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      div1: false,
      div2: false,
      div3: false
    }
  },
  handleClick: function(divNumber) {
    this.setState({
      divNumber: !this.state.condition
    });
  },


render() {
    return(
         <div>
            <div onClick={() => this.handleClick('div1')} className= { this.state.condition ? "positive active" : "positive"}></div>

            <div onClick={() => this.handleClick('div2')} className= { this.state.condition ? "neutral active" : "neutral"}>Not Sure</div>

            <div onClick={() => this.handleClick('div3')} className= { this.state.condition ? "negative active" : "negative"}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

Comment: Ok this makes sense, thank you - but now I'm getting "div 1 is not defined" am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the quotes between 'div1' on function call. Just added to answer 'div1', 'div2', and 'div3'